# Unable to set SeriesIdentifier of Birt chart using javascript

Tags: birt

I am trying to create a birt chart report with a dynamic series label.

I have created the aggregate data binding as the first(row["year"]), which will give results like '2020', but I don't know how to get this binding value in JavaScript. Please any ideas?

```
function afterDataSetFilled( series, dataSet, icsc )
{
    var chart = icsc.getChartInstance();

    importPackage(Packages.java.util);
    importPackage(Packages.org.eclipse.birt.chart.model.data.impl);
    importPackage(Packages.org.eclipse.birt.chart.model.component.impl);
    importPackage(Packages.org.eclipse.birt.chart.model.type.impl);
    importPackage(Packages.org.eclipse.birt.chart.model.attribute);

    var xAxis = chart.getAxes().get(0);
    var yAxis = xAxis.getAssociatedAxes().get(0);
    var xSerieDef = xAxis.getSeriesDefinitions().get(0);
    var ySerieDef1 = yAxis.getSeriesDefinitions().get(0);

    var dt = dataSet[row.year];

    ySerieDef1.getSeries().get(0).setSeriesIdentifier(dt);
}
```